# Use throttle in Angular 6

Tags: rxjs, angular6

I have a search engine and I want the search engine when I write not to pull a search with every letter that I am writing even when I have not finished typing what I am looking for. I know I can use the throttle or throttletime method (I do not know what the difference is between these two). But I do not know how to use them in my code.

It is an application in Angular 6. And this.spotify is a service that connects with the api of spotify. And the code portion is of a component that has this service injected.

```
  search(content:string){
  this.spotify.getArtists(content)
    .subscribe( (data:any) => {
      this.contentSearch = data;
    });
  }
```

Comment: It's debounceTime that you're looking for. Not throttle. There are dozens of tutorials, blog posts, and documentation explaining RxJS operators, and showing how to implement a typeahead.

Comment: Example: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples#http